# How to filter data in requests if that data is in a list?

Tags: python, list, python-requests, postman

I have a list of sampleId's named `sampleid_list`, now I want to do a requests and I only want to get the SampleId if that SampleId occurs in `sampleid_list`

**This is my code:**

```
import requests

sampleid_list = [592785, 592787, 592789, 592790, 592791, 592795, 592796]

headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token}
proxies = {'https': 'proxy.services.dekra.com:8080'}
url1 = 'https://**-**-***.***.com/odata/Results'

params_1 = (
    ('$filter','SampleId in ', sampleid_list),
    ('$select', 'ResultId, CompletedOn, EnteredValue, EnteredOn, TextValue\n'),
    ('$count', 'true'),
    ('$expand', 'Test($expand=Sample($select=SampleId)), Test($expand=TestType($select=Name)), Test($select=SpecificationStatus), ResultType($select=Name), Unit($select=Name)\n'),
)

response_1 = requests.get(url1, headers=headers, proxies=proxies, params=params_1)
r1 = response_1.json()
print(r1)
```

Now what makes it difficult is `SampleId` is not in the base url of `/Results` but expanded from `/Sample`

**My current output:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/data/GORGE/Desktop/VSprojects/EnergyZero/EnergyZero_API.py", line 156, in <module>
    response_1 = requests.get(url1, headers=headers, proxies=proxies, params=params_1)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 516, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 459, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 314, in prepare
    self.prepare_url(url, params)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 432, in prepare_url
    enc_params = self._encode_params(params)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 97, in _encode_params
    for k, vs in to_key_val_list(data):
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: share the full error details please.

Answer (score 0):

You bug:

`params` should be a `dict` or a `list` of tuples. Each tuple should contain 2 elements (key,val) however `params_1` is a `tuple` of tuples and you have more than 2 elements.

**Demo of the bug** (the third request will throw the exception you get in your code)

```
import requests

url = 'https://w3schools.com/python/demopage.php'

x = requests.get(url, params = {"model": "Mustang"})
print(x.status_code)

y = requests.get(url, params = [("model", "Mustang")])
print(y.status_code)

bug = requests.get(url, params = (("model", "Mustang","bug")))

print(bug)
```

Comment: if I comment the filter row out and run the code it works, but that's exactly not what I want because I want the filter parameter to be included

Comment: As I wrote - your tuples must have 2 elements only - key and value.

Comment: Okay I understand that so how can I reach my goal (filter the sampleId that are available in my list)

Comment: since I dont know what `'https://**-**-***.***.com/odata/Results'` is expecting to get  I find it hard to tell.

Comment: Its a private API so I cannot give  that information, buts its about the filter function

Comment: No one who can help....?